# Axios + .Net Core - Post com arquivo

Tags: .net, http, axios, .net-core

Preciso enviar os dados de um formulário juntamente com o arquivo com axios e retornar um JSON com .netcore, consigo receber o arquivo normalmente no controller porém os dados do formulario não consigo receber.
Segue código JS

```
function EditDocument() {
    let url = '/Documentos/Edit/';

      var documento = {
            Ano: getAno(),
            Assunto:getAssunto(), 
            DataEnvio: getDataEnvio(),
            CaminhoArq:null,
            DataAlteracao:null,
            DataEnvio: getDataEnvio(),
            Id: getId(),
            Numeracao: getNumeracao(),
            Observacoes: getObservacoes(),
            Status:null,
            Tipo: getTipo(),
            Usuario:null,
            UsuarioId: getUsuarioId(),

        };
      var data = new FormData();
       var file = getArquivo();
      data.append('file',file);
      data.append('documento',documento);
      data.append('id',documento.Id);
      url = url  + documento.Id;
      console.log(documento)
      axios.post(url, data)
        .then(function (response) {
          let modal = document.getElementById('myModalSucess');

          console.log(response.data.Usuario.user_nicename);

          let RespostaElement = document.getElementById('Resposta');
          let RespostaText = document.createTextNode(`Documento enviado númeração: ${response.data.Numeracao}/${response.data.Ano}`);
          RespostaElement.appendChild(RespostaText);
          let UsuarioElement = document.getElementById('Usuario');
          let UsuarioText = document.createTextNode(`Usuario de envio: ${response.data.Usuario.user_nicename}`);
          UsuarioElement.appendChild(UsuarioText);
          $(modal).modal('show');


        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            let modal = document.getElementById('myModalError');
            let resposta = error.data;
            $("#message").append(resposta);
            $(modal).modal('show');
        });

}
```

Se rodo um console.log antes de fazer a requisição com axios o objeto documento está preenchido com todos os dados que estão em tela.Porém na requisição se olho no debug do VSCode recebo dados null.

.Net

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id, IFormFile file,Documento documento)
        {

          System.Console.WriteLine(documento);
           if (id != documento.Id)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               try
               {

                   //verifica se foi enviado arquivo.
                   if (file != null)
                   {
                       string fileNewName = Convert.ToString(documento.Numeracao) + "_" + Convert.ToString(documento.Ano);
                       string fileNameExt;
                       try
                       {
                           fileNameExt = _arquivo.Upload(file, fileNewName);
                       }
                       catch (IOException)
                       {
                           return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status203NonAuthoritative, "Arquivo já existe");
                       }
                       if (_arquivo.FileExist(fileNameExt))
                       {
                           documento.CaminhoArq = fileNameExt;
                       }
                       documento.Status = StatusDoc.Enviado;
                   }
                   //caso não enviado mantem o caminho de arquivo anterior.
                   if (file == null)
                   {
                       documento.CaminhoArq =
                          _documentoService.GetCaminhoArq(id);
                       documento.Status = StatusDoc.Aberto;
                   }



                   documento.DataAlteracao = DateTime.Now;
                   await _documentoService.UpdateAsync(documento);

               }
               catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
               {
                   if (!_documentoService.Exist(documento.Id))
                   {
                       return NotFound();
                    }
                     return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Arquivo já existe");
                 }
              documento.Usuario = _login.GetUser();
              return Json(documento); 
        }
        return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status206PartialContent,"Documento enviado não valido verifique");
      }
```

Se alguém souber o que estou fazendo de errado e puder me ajudar, estou começando agora e não consegui encontrar nada para fazer funcionar, se acharem outros erros ou problemas no código estou aberto a criticas obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Sempre que você for dar post em um arquivo, você precisa utilizar o "multipart/form-data" para que o navegador possa partir esse arquivos em pedaços e mandar para o servidor. Veja uma explicação [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean).

Veja um exemplo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014086/13131762) com axios:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);
axios.post('upload_file', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Nota importante: Teste a recepção do arquivo no backend com algum REST client, como [inmsonia](https://insomnia.rest/).

Espero que eu tenha ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado Felipe! Vou estudar os links que  passou e testar

Comment: vc até consegue fazer isso sem mandar como formData e sem o multipart porém isso nunca  fica bom pois a outra maneira é base64 e isso deixa o arquivo enorme e tira essa capacidade do navegador de quebrar a request em diversos pequenos pedaços.

Comment: Eu consigo enviar o arquivo o problema é receber o objeto no backend ele chega vazio